# switch statment when button is pressed is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I want to execute a alert within a switch statement when I´m pressing a button, but it is not working. Even when I´m just having a alert in the prev function, there's no output on my website.

Why?

HTML Code: ( this is one of three "sections" )

```
<div class="service" id="service_1">

    <div class="img_service">

            <img src="image\background-313415.jpg" width="20%" height="auto">

    </div>

    <div class="text_service">

            Where does it come from?
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

           The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. 
             

    </div>

</div>
```

JS - Code:

```js
   

 var slider_1 = document.querySelector("#service_1");
var slider_2 = document.querySelector("#service_2");
var slider_3 = document.querySelector("#service_3");

var services_array = [];
services_array[0] = slider_1;
services_array[1] = slider_2;
services_array[2] = slider_3;

function prev() {
  alert("prev");

  var count = 0;

  switch (count) {
    case 0: // 0 = slider_1

      // goto slider_3;
      count = 2;
      alert(services_array[count]);

      break;

    case 1: // 1 = slider_2

      // goto slider_1;
      count--;

      break;

    case 2: // 2 = slider_3

      // goto slider_2;
      count--;

      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn_backward_service" onclick="prev()"><</button>
```

Comment: **Always**  check the error console and fix those errors. The console will tell you exactly what is wrong here. Speaking of the console `console.log()` is a much better way to debug than alerts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had not defined `slider_1`, `slider_2` and `slider_3`. And every time the code go through your switch block then it assign **2** to **count** hence every time it will go to  `services_array[2]` and it'll then break out the `switch`.

```js
var services_array = [];
services_array[0] = document.getElementById('service_1');
services_array[1] = document.getElementById('service_2');
services_array[2] = document.getElementById('service_3');



function prev()
{
    alert("prev");

    var count = 2;
    switch(count)
    {
        case 0: // 0 = slider_1
            // goto slider_1;
            alert(services_array[count]);
            console.log(services_array[count]);
            count++;
        break;

        case 1: // 1 = slider_2
            // goto slider_2;
             alert(services_array[count]);
             console.log(services_array[count]);
              count++;
        break;

        case 2: // 2 = slider_3
            alert(services_array[count]);
            console.log(services_array[count]);
            count++;
        
        break;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="service" id="service_1">

            Where does it come from?
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
</div>
<div class="service" id="service_2">
           The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. 
</div>
<div class="service" id="service_3">
 College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. 
</div>
<button id="btn_backward_service" onclick="prev()"> < </button>
```